# regex challenge to group different rules into only two groups

Tags: regex, go

I have the following data:

```
msg=hello  msg=hellohello age:  s35  { getAge } for  name=peter id="123"
```

I would like to use regex to classify them in the following group 1 (left of the colon) and group 2 (right of the colon) structure:

```
msg : hello  
msg : hello/hello 
age :   thirtyfive  { getAge } for  
name: peter'
id  : "123"
```

I come up with the following regular expression

```
([^,=\s]*)=([^,\s]*)|([^= ]*):  ([^=]*for)
```

This does the job except that I have an unfortunate constraint. I can only allow two regular expression groups. As you can see the "age" attribute and corresponding key are in group 3 and group 4, correspondingly.

How can I group them all in just two groups in regex?

Comment: which programing language are you using ?

Comment: @user: Try [`([^,=\s]*)[=:]\s*([^=:]*for|[^,\s]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/TPkC9W/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which programing language are you using ?

Because you didn't  reply, I'll provide a regex for `python` and `php`:

**PYTHON**:

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"([a-z]+)(?:=|:\s+)(\d+.*?for |[^ ]+)", "\\1: \\2\n", original, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

**PHP**:

```
$result = preg_replace('/([a-z]+)(?:=|:\s+)(\d+.*?for |[^ ]+)/sim', '\1: \2\n', $original);
```

---

Output:

```
msg: hello
  msg: hellohello
 age: 35  { getAge } for 
 name: peter
 id: "123"
```

Comment: sorry about the delay. I am using golang

Comment: actually I made a mistake, the age is in english rather than numbers. Could you update the regex? You dont need to show me the golang, I can convert it. Then I will take your answer. Thank you!